# CSS3 and Bootstrap 3 - How to place a div on top of 2 divs, between the two, in the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 in my application. I'm trying to create two rectangles, and one smaller rectangle which will be located on top of the two, in the middle of their "border", just like seen in the image I've attached. This is what I've done so far:
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 center">
            <!-- place holder for extra content-->
        </div> <!-- end of div lg col 3 -->
        <div  class="col-sm-3 center x">

        </div> <!-- end of div lg col 3 -->
        <div id="both">hello</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 center x">

        </div> <!-- end of div lg col 3 -->
        <div class="col-sm-3 center">
            <!-- place holder for extra content-->
        </div> <!-- end of div lg col 3 -->
</div><!-- end of first row div-->
```

CSS3:

```
.center.x{
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}

#both{
    width:100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
.x{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background: #9ba3f7;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L742tx4y/).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

position the last center element as absolute , offset the element to center and give top margin by calculation so that it comes to vertical center or calculate it with javascript. Keep your code simple, I didnt get why do you have 4 div in a row and it show only 2 div.

Check the fiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/hdvp0052/

HTML

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 center x">DIV 1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 center x">DIV 2</div>
       </div><!-- end of first row div-->
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 center x y">DIV 3</div>
```

CSS

```
 .center.x{
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
.x{
    height:300px;
    background: #9ba3f7;
}
.y{
   height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px
}
```